# What is $\phi(k)$ in $\sum_{k=1..n} \phi(k)\lfloor n/k \rfloor^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I would like to compute a general $n$-term of a sequence
$$ 1, 5, 12, 24, 37, 61, 80, \dots$$
However I do not understand what $\phi$ refers to in the formula at http://oeis.org/A018806:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k)\lfloor n/k \rfloor^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [Euler totient function](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Euler_phi_function).

$\varphi(n)$ is the number of integers between 1 and $n$ that have [no common factors with](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Relatively_prime) $n$.  For example, $\varphi(9) = 6$, because 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, and 8 have no common factors with 9.

Wikipedia should have a lot of discussion.  If you need a good introduction, any book on elementary number theory will contain one, and there is a section in *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.